# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: _e_0uWl - Browser "breaks"

Tags: javascript, safari, referenceerror

We have a really weird issue on Safari 6.0.4:

The users can happily surf on our page and suddenly they get this on all our pages:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: _e_0uWl

Other sites still work fine. The only thing to fix it is to restart Safari.
The website is built on asp.net with jquery, etc. 
We searched all our code and couldn't find anything that would reference: `_e_0uWl`

All extensions are disabled.
What confuses me is that this is not just happening on a page and if you move away it works again, no, once it is broken, it stays broken. What could make a browser do this?

**Update**: This happend again a few times, but with different variable names:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: _e_028Y
```

And we even  had it with Firefox on Windows machine. So it's not a Safari only issue.

**Spec**:
ASP.NET 4.5 on IIS7 with the MS Optimization Framework for bundling and minification. jQuery 1.9.2, Micosoft Ajax Control Toolkit.

Comment: Are you maybe using user controls, or asp controls which may be creating dynamic names on page request?

Comment: We are using user controls, but scanning the page we couldn't find the variable anywhere. And I don't think that asp.net names the variables different every day.

Comment: oh, are you using something like asp's output cache to cache the entire page and/or specific user controls? The variable name surely looks like it is something system generated.

Comment: No caching, except for the bundling of javascript files. But we did go through all of them and couldn't find any reference to the variable. And why would  this happen suddenly and then just stay? Over all pages in our system.

Comment: In Safari developer tools, click the button to "pause on all exceptions", this should take you to the problem area in your code. If it's a minified library, you can prettify the print and try again.

Comment: What's the site that you got the message on?

Comment: It's our own application and it's not public. So I can't give you a sneak peak unfortunately.

Comment: Could you copy paste the generated HTML, removing any sensitive data first if needed?

Comment: If possible paste page code, or paste link of page if Live, or paster generated html, with js dependencies, that is the only proper way to help. although this happens if you have updated ajax library. or the page developed using different version of AJAX library.

Comment: @Remy Please provide minimum framework, after removing private data, or Please close the meaning less discussion, Sorry for this..

Comment: We are going to need more details to work from then what you provided. Off the top of my head: Does this occur on page load? How many times does it occur per page? Does this occur in Internet Explorer? Have you tried using Firebug in Firefox or like @DavidGilbertson suggested, Safari developer tools and tried to follow the exception back to the source via catching it or stepping through execution? Have you checked the source code that the browser is given from the website for these variable names? Is your code using a plugin like Flash or something more obscure like XStandard editor?

Comment: Sounds like an uglyfied variable, maybe the jquery.min.js contains it. Can you give a link to the webpage? You should check, maybe sy injected a virus downloader, which creates this variable runtime...

Comment: What is in the console?
There is a script panel in firefox and a watch tab in that. I think you can find the origin of your exception with that.

Comment: If you can repeat the problem on JSfiddle, surely we could figure it out.

Comment: @SpencerLockhart We can't really recreate the problem unfortunately.

Comment: @inf3rno We went through all scripts that are being downloaded and could't find any reference to this variable.

Comment: @Turnerj There is a flash on some pages for file-upload. But once we have the error, it stays on all pages, even on those without flash. But we will try the developer tools again.

Answer (score 0):

As a very quick analysis:

- It's happening on several browsers, so it's not a browser bug but a bug in code.
- The variable is not hard referenced in your code, so either a) it is generated when your code is minified/obfuscated (is the code minified?) or b) the variable is requested runtime, but it does indeed not exist anywhere in your code, hence the error or c) it is in some external library. Do you use those?
- The problem occurs on a certain moment and then persists. Thus, either a) the server suddenly sends specific script tags that were not sent along before or b) the server suddenly sends some data in all pages that trips up a client-side function or c) you stored something in localstorage, and it's broken now, and it will be broken for all future page-reloads.

Now eliminate all cases one by one and you might find the answer. Use the debugger!

Comment: Yeah, sounds reasonable. We don't use localstorage, except if it happens somewhere in jquery or jquery UI.

Answer (score 0):

@ my view :

First of all  If possible run this code on @localhost with or without debugging enabled ;
else run on a different webserver or a different web farm

Second : If this issue persists , check which page or pages the issue occurs 
a high quality debugging is necessary , check whether any user controls is in this page or ajax(non blocking) requests in this page , please disable this one by one , finally check if there is , as this does not solve,  please double check javascripts  , if any minified or obfuscated and try to remove that .

NB: please build and run on the same runtime environment , please delete all files in the deploy/lib dir and do a clean build.

Comment: We don't know how to reproduce this error. So running it on localhost will not help. Also, personally I never had it so far.
Since we cannot reproduce it, it's a bit difficult to disable all controls step by step. If the controls are not there, people cannot use the app anymore...

Comment: @Remy : dont you have a staging and testing servers

Comment: Yes, we do. But we can't reproduce it on command. It just happens for the users and non could tell us when exactly it happens.